# Why is my Minecraft crashing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Here it the crash report that I am getting:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb1e71986c,
>   pid=3128, tid=5796
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build
>   1.8.0_25-b18) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops) Problematic frame: C 
>   [ig8icd64.dll+0x63986c]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
>   client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\hs_err_pid3128.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. See problematic frame
>   for where to report the bug.
>
> AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely
>   be removed in a future release

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me. It chrashes when your computer can handle a big amount of lag. It can crash if you install alot of mods, by exploding to much TNT or by block render.